# Automatically added ConstraintLayout dependency in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-constraintlayout, build-dependencies

Just I update my studio **(version 2.3)** and build version **('25.0.0')**,

now, when i try to create new activity then automatically `constraintlayout` `dependency` added in my `build.gradle` file.

and layout render as parent `ConstraintLayout`, can anyone know how to remove this dependency when activity is created.

**Before activity creation gradle code.**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

**After activity creation gradle code.**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Create empty activity(new->activity->empty activity) if you don't want `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify default template layout file in Android Studio resources, path to it:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout
```

Edit file `simple.xml.ftl` and change layout to your choice, notice that some layouts require additional elements (e. g. `LinearLayout` needs `android:orientation`), save file and create activity in Android Studio, it should work.

Mine looks like this (I have 2.2.3 so I have RelativeLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
</#if>
    android:id="@+id/${simpleLayoutName}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
</#if>
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

<#if isNewProject!false>
    <TextView
<#if includeCppSupport!false>
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
</#if>
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</#if>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i am using linux ubuntu

Comment: principle will be simlar, go to Android Studio folder to the path I wrote or search for file `simple.xml.ftl`

Comment: this is working but you given half answer, what i do then automatically gradle dependency will not add

Comment: I assume gradle auto-import needed resources after creating new Activity, you could disable auto-import gradle but this option is deleted in newer versions of Android Studio and I wouldn't recommended. It is more gradle problem than Android Studio.

Comment: need to more investigate

Answer (score 2):

latest Android support Constraint layout automatically if still you are not able to use than in build.gradle file add this dependency **implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'**